# What is the equivalent of dash callback in plotly js

Tags: django, plotly-dash, plotly.js

I had to build a dashboard , so dash seemed pretty easy. But i faced lot of issues integrating with flask or django.

So I had to rebuild the dashboard with django framework with plotly.js , while using plotly dash `@app.callback()` was very fast and quick in updating the graphs. To mock the similar behaviour I tried using ajax in django and plotly.js. Even though the job gets done using ajax, i see there is a lag in performance, it takes 3-4 secs to render the updated graph.

Is there a better or efficient way to achieve similar performance of dash callbacks in django/ajax ?
Just because every time i have to read the csv file during ajax call , hinders my performance ?

sample backend code for ajaxcall

```
def itemsAjax(request):

    if request.is_ajax():
        
        itemsList = request.POST.get('items')
        
        #itemsList = ast.literal_eval(itemsList)
        #itemsList = [n.strip() for n in itemsList]
        itemsList=itemsList.split(',')
        
        daterange = request.POST.get('daterange').split('-')
        franchise = request.POST.get('franchise')
        startDate = dt.strptime(daterange[0].strip(),'%m/%d/%Y')
        endDate = dt.strptime(daterange[1].strip(),'%m/%d/%Y')
        df = at.readData()
        flag = ut.determineFlag(startDate,endDate)
        df = at.filter_df_daterange(df,startDate,endDate)
        itemTrend_df = at.getDataForItemsTrend(df,startDate,endDate,flag)
        
        
        
        itemTrend_plt = [{'type':'scatter',
                            'x' : itemTrend_df[itemTrend_df['S2PName']==item]['S2BillDate'].tolist(),
                            'y' : itemTrend_df[itemTrend_df['S2PName']==item]['totSale'].tolist(),
                            #'text' : itemTrend_df[itemTrend_df['S2PName']==item]['Hover'],
                            'mode' : 'markers+lines',
                            'name' : item
        }for item in itemsList]

        return JsonResponse({'itemTrend_plt':itemTrend_plt})

    else:
        return HttpResponse(' Not authorised!')
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your problems integrating Dash with Flask? Since Dash is based on Flask, they should integrate seamlessly.

Comment: The issue is, my application needs session cookie management, talking to database etc. Also there are sub modules that are mostly like full stack, hence direct integration of the dash app inside flask or django was not an option for us.